# Resetting footnote's numbers per page

Tags: numbering, footnotes

I use different methods to reset the footnote number, but some of them don't work properly. I want to know the reason. See page 2 when uncomment one of the "Not OK" methods.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% OK
%\usepackage{zref-perpage} 
%\zmakeperpage{footnote}

% OK
%\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}

% Not OK
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}

% Not OK
%\makeatletter
%\@addtoreset{footnote}{page}
%\makeatother

\newcount\footCounter
\newcommand{\mfootnote}[1]{%
    \loop
    \ifnum\footCounter<#1
        \footnote{Test}%
        \advance\footCounter by 1%
    \repeat\footCounter0%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    Text\mfootnote{3}\
    \lipsum[1-3] Text Text Text Text kk\mfootnote{5}\ Text
    \lipsum[1-4]\mfootnote{5}

\end{document}
```

---

I have another MWE too:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Not OK
%\usepackage{zref-perpage} 
%\zmakeperpage{footnote}

% OK
%\usepackage[bottom,perpage]{footmisc}

% Not OK
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}

% Not OK
%\makeatletter
%\@addtoreset{footnote}{page}
%\makeatother

\newcount\footCounter
\newcommand{\mfootnote}[1]{%
    \loop
    \ifnum\footCounter<#1
        \footnote{Test}%
        \advance\footCounter by 1
    \repeat\footCounter0%
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Parsian-Regular.ttf} % https://github.com/SajadKazemi/Parsian/tree/main

\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \ptext[1-2]\mfootnote{5}
    \ptext[1-2]\mfootnote{5}
    \ptext[1-2]\mfootnote{5}
    \ptext[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: the ones you mark not ok can not work as the footnotes have been allocated numbers before page breaking. That is why `footmisc` offers code to implement this.